# How to compile Javascript console application locally?

Tags: javascript, v8

I am a beginner in Javascript, I decided to practice Javascript by problem solving using it, I found an [online judge](https://github.com/DMOJ/v8dmoj) that accepts `Javascript V8 4.8.0` code.
So, I searched online to get that version of Javascript V8 on my machine, but I couldn't find any easy way, All the pages were explaining how to build it, and it seems to be a process that I don't need to go through.

Is there an easy way to compile and run command line apps written in Javascript on my machine?

> Note: I don't want to use node.js because I tried using it's I/O and
>   as a beginner I think it is complex in some way.

**Update:** I found that package manager [pbox.me](http://pbox.me/packages/v8) which provides a version of V8 JavaScript Engine and I managed to install it.
Yet another problem appeared: whenever I try to run a js file writing `d8 myfile.js` in command line nothing happens as if it is an empty program, knowing that I tryied to `d8.exe` file and it is working, and I made sure the PATH is inserted in the environment variables.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd strongly (re-)consider using NodeJS.

Comment: Just use NodeJS. Also what do you mean by "an online judge"? Node's I/O is really simple actually, just give it a try.

Comment: I know that Node.js could do the job, but I also know that it is more convenient using standalone V8 compiler, and it seems like there is just a small problem here, because I already have the software. 
@bool3max by "an online judge" I meant Codeforces.com

Comment: Another vote to use NodeJS. There will be a lot more people on here (SO) that could help with Node's I/O than probably any other environment.

Comment: It isn't more convenient to use a standalone V8 compiler. That's like saying it is more convenient to use an engine instead of a car.

Comment: @Alexander I'd argue it is not more convenient to use a standalone V8 compiler. You'd have been done already if you'd used NodeJS. Remember the question you asked ~11 hours ago about V8 that SO closed? It's a half-day later, you've run into another problem, instead of just using proven tech with tons of tutorials and resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get started with JavaScript is probably to use it in a browser. You can type simple things directly into the browser's JavaScript console (check the menu); or you can embed your code in a simple HTML document.

If you want, you can even pretty easily implement the `readline()`/`print()` functions, so you can pretend to be doing stdin/stdout based I/O: just read from an array of strings, and send output to `console.log` (or create DOM nodes if you want to be fancy and/or learn how to generate dynamic website content by hand).

Side note: V8 4.8 is severely outdated, don't use it to execute code you haven't written yourself.

Comment: I ended up using node.js Implementing the readline() / print() functions myself.